# Error when try to install react-native project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

When I try to create new react-native project
command: npx react-native init myproject

I have follow errors:

> ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
> npm WARN While resolving: react-shallow-renderer@16.14.1
> npm WARN Found: react@18.0.0
> npm WARN node_modules/react
> npm WARN   peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.1
> npm WARN   node_modules/react-native
> npm WARN     react-native@"*" from the root project
> npm WARN     1 more (@react-native-community/cli)
> npm WARN   1 more (use-sync-external-store)

Answer (score 0):

To create a new react app, I normally use `npx create-react-app app-name` for JS and `npx create-react-app app-name --template typescript` in case that you want to develop it in TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

Remove the global react-native installed in your workspace and re-install:

1. `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`
2. `npm uninstall -g react-native`
3. `npm install -g react-native`
4. `npm upgrade -g`